# Poisson Process interpretation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

I am working on a homework problem which is related to Poisson processes but it all boils down to finding the probability that a sum of $2$ exponential random variables is greater than a third exponential r.v., all three of them having the same mean and being independent.

I wanted to bash it out, but it seems I am making a mistake somewhere and would be grateful if you could help me.

Let $X,Y,Z$ be $Exp(\lambda)$ independent random variables.

$P(X+Y>Z) = \int _{0}^{\infty}\int _{0}^{\infty}\int _{z-y}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \lambda e^{-\lambda z} dxdydz$ if I am not mistaken.

The problem is that this integral does not converge. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

**Edit** In the context of the problem we probably have to condition on $Y < Z$, say

Comment: The integral $$\int_{z-y}^\infty$$ should read $$\int_{\max(0,z-y)}^\infty$$ But of course this is not the most direct way to solve the question...

Comment: Yes, you can use the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, but wanted to see why this approach doesn't work

Comment: And why not use $$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^{x+y}\lambda e^{-\lambda z}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,dz\,dy\,dx\ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out by Did, it is easier to use
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\int_0^{x+y}\lambda e^{-\lambda z}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,dz\,dy\,dx &=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y} (1-e^{-\lambda(x+y)})\,dx\,dy\\
&=(1-1/4)\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,dx\,dy\\&=3/4.
\end{align}

Your approach does't work because you are integrating from $z-y$, but $z-y$ can be negative and you don't take this into account.